# Ansible loop control and with_together loop

Tags: ansible

I need to include `test.yml` which should run in loops (with_together) and I need to change the loop vars to avoid conflicts inside `test.yml`.
How can I use `loop_control` to change the `loop_var` when nested loops are used?
Sample Code:

```
include: test.yml
with_together:
  - "{{ some_list }}"
  - "{{ other_list }}"
loop_control:
  loop_var: ?
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using ansible 2.5 or above, you can use the `loop` combined with the `zip` filter, instead of `with_together`.

```
   - name: loop test
     include: test.yml
     loop: "{{ some_list | zip(other_list) | list }}"
     loop_control:
       loop_var: variable_name_in_test_yml
```

Have a look at the [Ansible docs](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_loops.html#with-together) for more examples.

Comment: But how can we refer the iterators from each of the lists? It is 'item.0' and 'item.1' if we didn't use loop_control

Comment: Using `loop_var` it is variable_name_in_test_yml.0 and variable_name_in_test_yml.1